# Sitecore RSS feed generation error in Sitecore 9.1 SXA site

Tags: sxa, rss

We want to configure the `RSS feed` for news/events items in the `SXA` site with two separate `RSS` links for each type. Feed generation works for news, but throws errors to the events feed.

[image]

Please suggest what the issue will be for this particular item type.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue, this might be caused when the item that has `Feed Renderer` rendering contains no versions in context language and fields that are set up in RSS design do not exist as a result. Therefore, i.e `__Updated` or `__Never Publish` fields under the statistics section will result in this error. As the error is not self-explanatory, it is best to try a different item to drive our feed to exclude this issue or if the listing is fairly small manually try to find the faulty item.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some issue with data related to date in your Event section. If your data is huge and can't check manually you can try to update the `RSS query` in `Data\Link`

[image]

Like here I have added Publish Date check, you can also try some queries with your feed.

Also before setting up the query here, it is good to test it in `PowerShell`, so if it works there then `RSS` feed should be good e.g.
[image]

```
get-item -Path "master:" -query"/sitecore/content/Site/Home//*[@Publish Date > '20220101']"
```